# Why is this function not properly returning true or false when the if statement is working?

Tags: javascript, return

Part of the code I'm writing prompts a user for their name and compares it to a list.
There is a problem indicated below where -- even though the if statement and loop works fine -- the function is not returning true or false.

What is my problem here? Let me know if I can make anything more clear.

```
function callback() {
    let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
        compareName(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }   
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "data.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function compareName(value){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = value;
    let name_arr = value.split(",");
    for (let i = 0; i < name_arr.length; i++) {
        if (name == name_arr[i]){
            alert("true"); //THIS WORKS!!
            return true;
        }
    }
    alert("false"); //THIS WORKS TOO!
    return false;
}

window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{ 
     let name = prompt("What is your name?", "");
     name;
     callback();
     if (!compareName()) { //THIS IS NOT WORKING! it just skips the whole if statement.
        document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = "you are not on the list"
     }
     else {
        //stuff happens
     }
```

Comment: You are not passing anything to `compareName`. Is this intentional?

Comment: You pass nothing to the `compareName()` function.

Comment: @KenBekov I see, is there a way to check if compareName is true/false with "value"? Since I can't put "value" there.

Comment: It seems you want to put the `innerHTML` assignment inside the `onreadystatechange` callback